# How to return the last primary key inserted

Tags: sql, t-sql, informix, scope-identity

I ask about alternative or similar query in `informix` to perform the following:

```
INSERT INTO days (depcode,studycode,batchnum) values (1,2,3);SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY();
```

I want a query to return the  `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` during insertion statement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know that in t-sql you have the `OUTPUT` statement?
Where `[KEY]` is the column name of your primary key and `@OUT_KEY` is a variable you need to declare

```
INSERT INTO days
(
  depcode,
  studycode,
  batchnum
)
OUTPUT INSERTED.[KEY] INTO @OUT_KEY
VALUES
(
  1,2,3
)
```

EDIT

For informix you can use

```
SELECT DBINFO( 'sqlca.sqlerrd1' )
FROM systables
WHERE tabid = 1;
```

Presuming your pk column is SERIAL

Comment: this is the answer, please can u explain what u do .what is `tabid`?

Comment: tabid is a field on systables which as an id for each table. it's explained here http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/idshelp/v10/topic/com.ibm.esqlc.doc/esqlc214.htm   The sqlca and sqlerrd1 are explained here http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/idshelp/v10/topic/com.ibm.esqlc.doc/esqlc214.htm

Answer (score 0):

I use this sql statement `Select @@Identity` after I inserted rows. It gives me the ID of the last inserted row. I´m using an accessdatabase. I don´t know if it work with your database.

Comment: Maybe it didn´t work with informix. What kind of error you get?

Comment: Never use @@Identity for this in SQL Server. It wilgive you the wrong answer if anyone ever puts a trigger on the table that inserts to another table with an identity. ANd you may not even know it happened until your data hase been so throughly messed up that it is unfixable. Scope_identity() or the output clasue is what you want to use.