# Select of last inserted id return always 0 in informix

Tags: sql, informix

I’ve followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6843121/how-to-return-the-last-primary-key-inserted) example to get the last id of an inserted record, problem is that my application sometimes returns `0`. I've tried to test it using sql developer

```
INSERT INTO ...
execute function sysmaster:yieldn(1); // wait 1 second
select dbinfo('sqlca.sqlerrd1') from informix.systables where tabid=1;
```

always returns 0. The 1 second waiting is just to simulate traffic in my application.

Can someone explain me what does `dbinfo('sqlca.sqlerrd1')` means.

**PS:**

I've tried the example from IBM [site](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGU8G_11.50.0/com.ibm.sqls.doc/ids_sqs_1487.htm)

When I execute:

```
insert into fst_tab VALUES (0,1);
insert into fst_tab VALUES (0,4);
insert into fst_tab VALUES (0,6);

execute function sysmaster:yieldn(1);
insert into sec_tab values (dbinfo('sqlca.sqlerrd1'));
select dbinfo('sqlca.sqlerrd1') from informix.systables where tabid=1;
```

it returns the right id but when I comment the insert line:

```
insert into fst_tab VALUES (0,1);
insert into fst_tab VALUES (0,4);
insert into fst_tab VALUES (0,6);

execute function sysmaster:yieldn(1);
//insert into sec_tab values (dbinfo('sqlca.sqlerrd1'));
select dbinfo('sqlca.sqlerrd1') from informix.systables where tabid=1;
```

then it returns `0`.

**PS2:**

my db:

- informix Dynamic Server 12.10.FC5
- IBM Informix JDBC Driver for IBM Informix Dynamic Server 3.70.JC2

Answer (score 2):

SQLCA (SQL Communication Area) contains information about the very latest executed SQL statement.

In this example:

```
INSERT INTO ...
execute function sysmaster:yieldn(1); // wait 1 second
select dbinfo('sqlca.sqlerrd1') from informix.systables where tabid=1;
```

SQLCA will contain results from `execute function`, not the `INSERT`. To obtain the latest inserted serial you must call `dbinfo('sqlca.sqlerrd1')` immediately after the `INSERT`.

Comment: hm and how u can explain example in PS when it return right id after waiting

Comment: I'll leave that to you as an exercise.

Comment: hm ok and can you explain my how I can secure that dbinfo will be called immediately after insert  in multithread application where I need  couple of insert in 1s ?

Comment: SQLCA is local to each database connection (session), so as long as you call `dbinfo` right after the `insert` in a thread, it will pick up information from that thread.

Comment: hm then I dont understand why it doesnt work in my application and how I can test it

Comment: there cant be some problem with informix db ? because this error occurs just on test db: 12.10.FC5 but in development db: 12.10.FC4 it works OK

Comment: You may want to include table definitions into the question.

Comment: @hudi As said in the site you’ve linked and by @mustaccio, the `sqlca.sqlerrd1` option returns a single integer that provides the last `serial` value that is inserted into a table. Now, the result to be valid this option must be used immediately after the insert statement, and in the same session. You get `0` because you have the call to the function `yiedln` in the middle. Be aware that the `serial` value must be inserted in a direct way, using procedures or triggers to insert it will invalidate the result. If still not working you have to show us what you're doing.

Comment: I know man. I use yiedln to try to simulate in sql developer which was wrong. But in my application I used this immediately and in one db it works and other no

Comment: @hudi can you give us the schema of the table where it does not work and the insert statement you use?